# Cannot obtain a lock - Already deleted lock file

Tags: transactions, wallet

I am trying to open Bitcoin Core of "Cannot obtain a lock on C:User/App..." I deleted the lock. file like previously suggested but cannot find a solution after that! If I reinstall will I loose the Bitcoins sent to me or can I use the same address but on an online wallet and will it receive the coins? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Did you rerun Bitcoin after deleting the file?

Comment: After the deleting the .lock file I did re-launch Bitcoin Core

Comment: Did the .lock file reappear after that?

Comment: Not that I can see!

Comment: What's the rest of the error message? What is the exact name and path of the file you deleted? What version of Bitcoin Core?